# Memory problem when generating plots with loops

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, memory, spyder

I'm trying to generate a lot of plots using loops on a dataframe.

Here is whats my dataframes looks like :

```
file = 'data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file,sep=";", header=0, na_values=['NA', ' ' , '.'])
df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], dayfirst=True)
df['week'] = df['datetime'].dt.isocalendar().week
df['month'] = df['datetime'].dt.month
df['hour']=df['datetime'].dt.hour
df['day']=df['datetime'].dt.day
df['day_name']=df['datetime'].dt.day_name()

df=df.set_index(['datetime'])
   

df=df.rename(columns={'data1':'d1','data2':'d2','data3':'d3','data4':'d4','data5':'d5','data6':'d6','data7':'d7','data8':'d8','data9':'d9','data10':'d10','data11':'d11','data12':'d12','data13':'d13','data14':'d14','data15':'d15','data16':'d16'})

df=df[['d1','d2','d3','d4','d5','d6','d7','d8','d9','d10','d11','d12','d13','d14','d15','d16','week','month','hour','day','day_name']]

df19=df.loc['2019-01':'2019-12']
df20=df.loc['2020-01':'2020-12']
```

The dataframe contain data for every hour between 01/01/2019 00:00 to 31/12/2020 23:00.

I want to plot every day tendancies, for the 2 years.

Here is the code I made

```
if not os.path.exists('C:/test/jours'): #Create a subdirectory for my plots
    os.mkdir('C:/test/jours')

def graph19(a): #Create a fonction for ploting a specific row for the year 2019
    if not os.path.exists('C:/test/jours/2019'):
        os.mkdir('C:/test/jours/2019')
    for i in range (1,13):
        if not os.path.exists('C:/test/jours/2019/'+str(a)):
            os.mkdir('C:/test/jours/2019/'+str(a))
            
        for l in range (1,32):
            if not os.path.exists('C:/test/jours/2019/'+str(a)+'/'+str(i)):
                os.mkdir('C:/test/jours/2019/'+str(a)+'/'+str(i))
            try :
                folder19='C:/test/jours/2019/'+str(a)+'/'+str(i) #way to the saving directory
                maxima=df19[a].max()+50 #setting up my maximum value for yaxis
                plt.figure(figsize=[18,10])
                a19=df19[[a]][(df19["month"]==i)&(df19["day"]==l)] #The values I want to plot
                plt.plot(a19)
                plt.title(df19.loc[(df19["month"]==i)&(df19["day"]==l)]['day_name'].values[2]) #Here I want the graph title to be the day of the week i'm ploting
                plt.ylim(bottom=0,top=maxima)
                name=str(l)
                plt.savefig(os.path.join(folder19,name)) 
                plt.close(None) #Trying to close the fig to preserve memory
                plt.clf() # same as above
            except :
                continue
            
            
    return

def graph20(a): #Same fonction but for 2020
    if not os.path.exists('C:/test/jours/2020'):
        os.mkdir('C:/test/jours/2020')
    for i in range (1,13):
        if not os.path.exists('C:/test/jours/2020/'+str(a)):
            os.mkdir('C:/test/jours/2020/'+str(a))
            
        for l in range (1,32):
            if not os.path.exists('C:/test/jours/2020/'+str(a)+'/'+str(i)):
                os.mkdir('C:/test/jours/2020/'+str(a)+'/'+str(i))
            try :
                folder20='C:/test/jours/2020/'+str(a)+'/'+str(i)
                plt.figure(figsize=[18,10])
                a20=df20[[a]][(df20["month"]==i)&(df20["day"]==l)]
                plt.plot(a20)
                plt.title(df20.loc[(df20["month"]==i)&(df20["day"]==l)]['day_name'].values[2])
                plt.ylim(bottom=0)
                name=str(l)
                plt.savefig(os.path.join(folder20,name))
                plt.close(None)
                plt.clf()
            except :
                continue
            
            
    return

for m in df.columns :
    graph19(m)
    graph20(m)
```

I'm using both commands :

```
plt.close(None)
plt.clf()
```

at the end of the loop in order to close the plots I made to preserve memory, but the RAM i used keep on increasing and I can't reach the end of my loops :/ (sorry for the french screen :D )

[image]

Does anybody have any idea how I could preserve my memory fro increasing like that?

Thanks a lot guys

Edit : I'm using Spyder, don't know if it helps

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a known issue with both Spyder and Jupyter. People have reported that adding in your `for` loops this code: `import gc; gc.collect()` fixes it. Please try that and let us know if it works for you.

Comment: Hello, I tried to add gc.collect() but it did'nt seems to help that much. One other thing I noticed is that even when I stop the program or if a smaller loop can reach his end, the memory used won't go down until I totally shut down Spider

Comment: Well, that's the best advice I can give you at the moment. Sorry to hear it doesn't work better.